# How to prevent Evince from automatically opening PDF files?

Tags: evince

I am not sure what is wrong with my computer but it automatically opens PDF files using Evince whenever I download them from Chrome. How could I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation:

AFAIK, Google chrome remembers the downloading preference for each file type (exe, pdf, zip... etc) that a user inputs. This has nothing to do with a specific program (in your case **evince**) because, Ubuntu itself uses necessary programs which are set as default to open file types. Such like, if the option seen in below image is selected for each file type, it will inherit the same preference to that selected types individually & opens/executes with a default assigned program.

---

I'd say this is quiet simple yet an unnoticeable option. Below should fix your problem as it took me a while to figure out why.. :)

- Just right click or hit on a **PDF** file to download from any link
- While the process shows downloading; simply click on the arrow shows next the file; `un-tick` **"Always Open Files of This Type"** if its select (`ticked`).

[image]

Just tested on my pc which sorted the issue. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: here it doesn't work, Ubuntu 22.04.2, Gnome 42.5, with Evince and Zhatura and sadly it still opens the Chrome plugin, I had to cofigure Chrome from Settings > Advanced > Privacy and security. Select Site Settings > PDF documents.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you don't want to use evince but another pdf viewer, you can go to `Settings > System > Details` and config every default app that will trigger whenever you try to open a given file.